# sed and single quote [']

Tags: sed, special-characters

I have a file readme.txt

in which I want to find the text

> 'I like pizza'

and remove the ' character
with sed cmd and to modify to:

> I like pizza

I have tried with this script

#!/bin/bash

```
echo $1'/readme.txt'

$1/build.ninja
sed -i "s|\'I like pizza\'|I like pizza|g" $1/readme.txt
```

but i does not work

Comment: Try: `sed -E -i "s|'(I like pizza)'|\\1|g"`

Comment: What was wrong with `sed -i "s/'//g" $1/readme.txt` or `sed -i "s|'I like pizza'|I like pizza|g" $1/readme.txt`? See https://ideone.com/O4YurK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all single quotation marks you can use

```sh
sed -i "s/'//g" $1/readme.txt
```

Or, if you really simply want to replace a literal `'I like pizza'` with `I like pizza`, you can use

```sh
sed -i "s|'I like pizza'|I like pizza|g" $1/readme.txt
```

See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/O4YurK):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="'I like pizza'"
sed "s|'I like pizza'|I like pizza|g" <<< "$s"
sed "s|'||g" <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
I like pizza
```